# How do I resolve this dependency resolution error in yum?

Tags: centos, php, yum, imagemagick

When I run `yum update`, after dependency resolution I get the following error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php71w-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.w7.x86_64 (@webtatic)
           Requires: libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-18.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: ImageMagick-6.9.10.68-3.el7.x86_64 (base)
               Not found
Error: Package: php71w-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.w7.x86_64 (@webtatic)
           Requires: libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit)
           Removing: ImageMagick-6.7.8.9-18.el7.x86_64 (@base)
               libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit)
           Updated By: ImageMagick-6.9.10.68-3.el7.x86_64 (base)
               Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

My understanding is that ImageMagick wants to update to 6.9.10.68-3, but this doesn't provide `libMagickCore.so.5` or `libMagickWand.so.5`, so it's blocking the upgrade because that would stop `php71w-peclimagick` from working?

Is it actually impossible here to upgrade ImageMagick, or would I need to keep it at an earlier version? What's the best way forward?

Note: php71w* come from webtatic.

### Update

One possible fix is the following:

```
yum install yum-plugin-versionlock
yum versionlock ImageMagick
```

After this the current ImageMagick version is locked and the rest of the updates work.

Is this a suitable fix or can anyone suggest anything better?